# install Net::SSH2 with carton

Tags: perl, cpan, libssh2, cpanm

I want to install Net::SSh2 with [Carton](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Carton-v1.0.28/lib/Carton.pm):
I have locally installed libssh2-1.6.0.

exported all necessary LIBSSH2 variables

```
export LIBSSH2_INCLUDE=$HOME/lib/libssh2-1.6.0/include
export LIBSSH2_LIB=$HOME/lib/lib
export LIBSSH2_LDARGS="-lz"
```

and then call `carton install`

and here Carton still complains that dependency can't be found.

It is not clear to me why Carton does not see Env variables?

log:

```
$ ~/.cpanm/work/1469440056.31412/Net-SSH2-0.62 $ perl Makefile.PL lib=$HOME/libssh2/lib inc=$HOME/libssh2/include \
> # 56         ldargs="-lz"

The libssh2 library is required by this module.  If you don't have it, you can
download it from http://www.libssh2.org; you may also need OpenSSL, which can
be obtained from http://www.openssl.org , or libgcrypt, which can be obtained
from http://www.gnupg.org .

Debian:   sudo aptitude install libssh2-1-dev
OpenSUSE: sudo zypper in libssh2-1 libssh2-devel

You can pass your libssh2 lib and include dirs (and extra link args) on the
command line. E.g.:

    perl Makefile.PL lib=$HOME/libssh2/lib inc=$HOME/libssh2/include \
        ldargs="-lz"

These can also be set through the LIBSSH2_LIB/LIBSSH2_INCLUDE/LIBSSH2_LDARGS
environment variables.
```